# Printing a two dimensional array on different lines

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print a two dimensional array with 5 rows and 5 columns but when I print it, I instead get one line with "[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]" How do I print it so that I get a 5x5 grid?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class spil {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] grid=new int [5][5];

        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
    }

    public static void print(int[][] grid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(grid[i][j]+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the problem with your `print` method?

Comment: Have you tried calling your print method?

Comment: Could it be because you are calling `Arrays.deepToString(grid)` instead of `print(grid)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `Arrays::deepToString` in line 7 instead of your custom `print` mehthod.

Instead, use `print(grid);` to call your method.

Answer (score 1):

Check this;

```
   import java.util.Arrays;

   public class spil {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] grid=new int [5][5];
    print(grid);// you never called your function
   // System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));-----> This function was making all printing
}

public static void print(int[][] grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just call your print method:

```
public class Spil { 

   public static void main(String[]  args) {
      int[][] grid = new int[5][5]; 

      print(grid);
   } 

   public static void print(int[][] grid) {
      for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(grid[i][j] + " ");
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

And the output will be like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void print(int[][] grid) {
    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.printf("%4s", grid[i][j]);
           
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked better when printing out results for a two-dimensional matrix with a mixture of zeros and numbers.